# understanding this ini_set code

Tags: php, xampp

I am having trouble understanding this code

```
    define( 'APP_LIB'         , dirname(__FILE__) . '/loi'              );
    define( 'COMMON_LIB'   , dirname(__FILE__) . '/../pk2'   );
    define( 'COMMON_APP_LIB'  , dirname(__FILE__) . '/app-lib' );
    ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path') . ':'
. APP_LIB. ':'
. COMMON_LIB_PATH  . ':'
. COMMON_APP_LIB ':'
    );
    require_once 'loader.php';
```

I get this error :

> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'loader.php'

I think this error is related to that `ini_set` function
but my main problem is: what is the meaning of "`:`" in `ini_set` function (second argument)?

why we need to stick these path together to put them all in include path?

Answer (score 1):

The colons are to add multiple directories to the path. The PATH is set up like this :

```
.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php
```

So in order to add more directories, the colon is needed.  Since the loader is not found, echo out the include_path after the ini_set, and compare it to where loader.php is located.

Comment: Don't add that last : at the very end (it was missing the . anyway). When you do an ini_get for include_path (after adding the three new paths separated by :'s), its format should resemble the example given by @aynber above. It should have whatever was there initially plus your three paths. Make sure the new paths are correct and the overall format looks like that. Where loader.php actually is needs to be in that list of paths.